# Get current index/visible item of FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, pagination, visibility, react-native-flatlist

I have a scrolling view of posts. Each post has a corresponding user and I have a header that shows the user info of the current visible post. With Flutter this was simple, I just wrapped the post widget with a visibility detector. With React Native this is not very easy. I've tried `onViewableItemsChanged` but, since I am using a `fuction` not a `class`, that causes an error. I also tried some solutions that used `onScroll` and `onMomentumScrollEnd` but those all just stayed at index 0. How can I get the current index that is fully visible? If needed, I am fine with splitting up the pagination functions so I can just have a class with the UI and use `onViewableItemsChanged` but I don't know how to do that because the `handleLoadMore` function is used in the UI.

```
export default function PostsListView() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  const onScroll = useCallback((event: any) => {
    const slideSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
    const index = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / slideSize;
    const roundIndex = Math.round(index);
    console.log("roundIndex:", roundIndex);

    currentItem = roundIndex;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts() {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from("posts")
        .select("*")
        .order("date", { ascending: false })
        .range((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE, page * PAGE_SIZE - 1);
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        showAlert();
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      const newPosts = data.map((post: any) => new Post(post));
      setPosts((prevPosts) => [...prevPosts, ...newPosts]);
      setLoading(false);
      setHasMore(data.length === PAGE_SIZE);
    }

    async function fetchUsers() {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.from("posts").select("*");
      if (error) {
        showAlert();
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }

      const newUsers = data.map((user: any) => new User(user));
      newUsers.forEach((user) => {
        const userPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.uid === user.uid);
        user.posts = [...user.posts, ...userPosts];
      });
      setUsers((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, ...newUsers]);
    }

    fetchPosts();
    fetchUsers();
  }, [page]);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    if (!loading && hasMore) {
      setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = (event: any) => {
    const index = Math.floor(
      Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x) /
        Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width)
    );

    currentItem = index;
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      {loading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={posts}
          horizontal={false}
          directionalLockEnabled={true}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <HomePost
                post={item}
                user={
                  users.filter(function (u) {
                    return u.uid == item.uid;
                  })[0]
                }
                index={posts.indexOf(item)}
                loading={loading}
              />
              <SizedBox vertical={5} />
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.postId}
          onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          onScroll={onScroll}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={onScroll}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I’ve been diving into supabase to recreate the environment but I’m not quite there yet

Comment: @PhantomSpooks No, I have not found a solution that worked.

Comment: I've got a working supabase demo and I noticed that, at least in an expo snack, that it was necessary to hard reload the app rather than depending on the update as you type feature. I assume that this would mean that when working with expo physically, you would have to press r in the terminal after updating saves

Comment: For me, unmounting and remounting the flatlist while loading was incredibly weird, so I moved the loading indicator to appear above the flatlist. Regardless of whether the flatlist unmounted and remounted, I didnt get the error

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a [viewabilityConfig](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#viewabilityconfig) to the FlatList, you can use the [onViewableItemsChanged](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged) event to learn which items are on screen. You just have to make sure that both the viewabilityConfig and onViewableItemsChanged values never change:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
const API_URL = 'https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=25';
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);
  // wrapped in ref so that re-renders doesnt recreate it
  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    minimumViewTime: 100,
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: '90%',
  }).current;
  // wrapped in useCallback so that re-renders doesnt recreate it
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setVisibleItems(viewableItems.map(({ item }) => item));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then(setPosts);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {visibleItems.length > 0 && (
        <Text>
          Currently visible:{' '}
          {visibleItems
            .map((item) => item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name)
            .join(', ')}
        </Text>
      )}
      <View style={styles.flatlistContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={posts}
          renderItem={(props) => <Item {...props} />}
          viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const Item = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text>
        {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
      </Text>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.avatar }}
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  flatlistContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  itemContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/7mHtAePOy)

Comment: I did try this but it gives me the `Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported` error

Comment: That is why you use useRef and useCallback

Comment: I did. I also just tried it again using your `onViewableItemsChanged` and `viewabilityConfig` but got the same error.

Comment: Would you be willing to share a snack showing it?

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through and created a supabase app that resembles your use case and the onViewableItemsChanged approach should work:

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper';

import { SessionContext } from '../../Context';
import { supabase } from '../../initSupabase';
import PostItem from '../../components/PostItem';
const { height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

const totalPostsToGet = 2;

type Post = {
  post: {
    text: string;
    media: {
      type: string;
      source: string;
    };
  };
  id: number;
  created_at: string;
  uid: string;
};

export default function PostScreen(props) {
  const { session } = useContext(SessionContext);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);
  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    // minimumViewTime: 100,
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
  }).current;
  // wrapped in useCallback so that re-renders doesnt recreate it
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setVisibleItems(viewableItems.map(({ item }) => item));
  }, []);
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    if (!isLoading && hasMore) {
      setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session) return;
    const fetchLastPost = async () => {
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('posts')
        .select('*')
        .order('created_at')
        .range(0, 1);
      return data[0];
    };
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const lastPost = await fetchLastPost();
      console.log('last post', lastPost);
      const rangeStart = (page - 1) * totalPostsToGet;
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('posts')
        .select('*')
        .order('created_at', { ascending: false })
        .range(rangeStart, rangeStart + totalPostsToGet - 1);
      if (error) {
        console.log('error retrieving profile data', error);
      }
      if (data) {
        setPosts((prev) => prev.concat(data));
        // I couldnt figure out how PAGE_SIZE could be used to know that the last post was reached
        // so I just grab the  last post and look to see if its id is in current data
        const hasLastPost = Boolean(
          data.find((post) => post.id == lastPost.id)
        );
        setHasMore(!hasLastPost);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchPosts();
    // subscribe to database changes
    const subscription = supabase
      .channel(`Posts`)
      .on(
        'postgres_changes',
        {
          event: '*',
          schema: 'public',
          table: 'posts',
          // filter: `id=eq.${session.user.id}`,
        },
        (payload) => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          console.log('Post update');
          setPosts((prev) => {
            // either push new post or update existing one
            const postIndex = prev.findIndex(
              (post) => post.id == payload.new.id
            );
            if (postIndex < 0) return [...prev, payload.new];
            else {
              const newPosts = [...prev];
              newPosts[postIndex] = payload.new;
              return newPosts;
            }
          });
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      )
      .subscribe();
    return () => {
      supabase.removeChannel(subscription);
    };
  }, [session, page]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Currently visible:</Text>
      <View style={{ padding: 5, margin: 5 }}>
        {visibleItems.map((item) => (
          <Text>{item.post.text.substring(0, 30)}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>

      <View style={styles.flatlistContainer}>
        {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator />}
        <FlatList
          data={posts}
          keyExtractor={(item: Post) => item.id}
          horizontal={false}
          directionalLockEnabled
          onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
          renderItem={(props) => <PostItem {...props} />}
          viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  flatlistContainer: {
    height: height * 0.45,
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/DP0JpHr1Y?platform=web)

Comment: Adding the comment I made under the question: For me, unmounting and remounting the flatlist while loading was incredibly weird, so I moved the loading indicator to appear above the flatlist. Regardless of whether the flatlist unmounted and remounted, I didnt get the error about not being able to recreate  the viewabilityConfig on the fly

Answer (score 0):

You could get the currently viewable items with `onViewableItemsChanged` where you should get your information.

```js
<FlatList
  data={posts}
  horizontal={false}
  directionalLockEnabled={true}
  // this should return an array with following infos
  // [{
  //   item: {key: "key-12"},
  //   key: "key-12",
  //   index: 11,
  //   isViewable: true
  // }]
  onViewableItemsChanged={({changed, viewableItems}) => console.log(changed, viewableItems)}
  ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Intersection Observer API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which is an implementation you can use to detect when an element is visible on the screen or not.

Here's a very simple example where the green div is "observed". Whether it is visible or not is marked in state.

[Here's a working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-18-2-detect-visible-screen-element-10e7cr)

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react18-intersection-observer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Detect visible screen elemenet using intersection observer",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "author": "Wesley LeMahieu"
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);
```

**app.js**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const observer = useRef(null);
  const observerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const observerCallback = async (e) => {
    if (e.length) {
      setIsVisible(e[0].isIntersecting);
    } else {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (observerRef.current) {
      if (observer.current) {
        observer.current.disconnect();
        observer.current.observe(observerRef.current);
      } else {
        observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback);
        observer.current.observe(observerRef.current);
      }
    }
    return () => observer.current.disconnect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) {
      alert("Green box visible");
    } else {
      alert("Grey box visible");
    }
    console.log(isVisible ? "GREEN BOX VISIBLE" : "GREEN BOX NOT VISIBLE");
  }, [isVisible]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: isVisible ? "green" : "red",
          width: "10%",
          height: "3000px",
        }}
      >
        Visible
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: "90%" }}>
        <div
          style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", opacity: 0.6, height: "1000px" }}
        >
          Other div
        </div>
        <div
          ref={observerRef}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "green", opacity: 0.6, height: "1000px" }}
        >
          Observed Div
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", opacity: 0.6, height: "1000px" }}
        >
          Other div
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```